# Understanding C++ heap/stack allocations when passing dereferenced pointer by reference

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to understand what happens with object creation and destruction in this example.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Person {
public:
    const int name;
    Person() = delete;
    Person(int& name) : name(name) {
        std::cout << "Person " << name << " created" << std::endl;
    }
    Person(const int& name) : name(name) {
        std::cout << "Person " << name << " created -- copy constructor" << std::endl;
    };
    ~Person() {
        std::cout << "Person " << name << " destroyed" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Family {
public:
    Person mom, dad;
    Family() = delete;
    Family(Person& m, Person& d) : mom(m), dad(d) {
        std::cout << "Family created" << std::endl;
    };
    Family(const Person& m, const Person& d) : mom(m), dad(d) {
        std::cout << "Family created -- copy constructor" << std::endl;
    };
    ~Family() {
        std::cout << "Family destroyed" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person* m = new Person(1);
    Person* d = new Person(2);
    Family f(*m, *d);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
Person 1 created -- copy constructor                                                                                                    
Person 2 created -- copy constructor                                                                                                    
Family created                                                                                                                          
Family destroyed                                                                                                                        
Person 2 destroyed                                                                                                                      
Person 1 destroyed
```

So I am not entirely sure how to interpret this. I've been taught that anything I heap-allocate using the `new` keyword should subsequently be `delete`-d. And stack variables are lost when the object moves out of scope. My understanding is like this. If instead of accepting `Person& m` by reference I took it without the `&`, like `Person m`, then `m` would be copied here (on the stack) and I'd have a memory leak because the heap-allocated `new Person("Jane")` would never be deleted.

But since I am taking it by reference, do I still have a memory leak? Both `m` and `d` have their destructors called, but does this also free the heap-memory? And how can I think of `Family.dad`? Is this a stack variable? If so, then is the entire `Family` considered a scope?

I am quite confused by this example and don't really know how to reason about it. Also, do I still have a memory leak here since I never explicitly `delete` the two `Person` objects?

Comment: You should output the value of `this` as well when creating and destroying objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add copy-constructor to see the whole picture.

Although `Family::Family` gets the objects by reference, it then copies them into the members `mom` and `dad`.  So the destructor invocations you observe actually occur when those members get destructed.

The original objects are not freed - until the program exits.

As for the location of `Person` instances you create using `new` - they are allocated in the "free store", as per C++ Standard. Typically, it means they reside on the heap.

OTOH, `Family` instance (along with all its members) has an "automatic storage". With most of popular compilers/platforms, this means it's allocated on the stack.

Comment: I added a copy constructor to `Family` and to `Person` by using the signature `Family(const Person& m, const Person& d)`. Is this correct?

Comment: @Pavlin A copy constructor copies an object of "its own" type. So they should be `Family(const Family&)` and `Person(const Person&)`.

Comment: Awesome thanks, that really clears things up! Thanks for the really comprehensive answer, I got it now, thanks!

Comment: So just a quick follow up. If I wanted to avoid any and all copies, I probably need to change the `Family` member types to be `Person*` instead of `Person`?

Comment: @Pavlin your last comment opens the who issue of ownership - who is responsible for the lifetime of the `Person*` members and what happens when a `Family` object is copied / destroyed?  If you can't find the answers to this please post another question.  Note that object lifetime is a design question and only when this is resolved should coding be started.

Comment: @Pavlin if by design the both "persons" are guaranteed to outlive the "family" instance, the latter may store the former by reference (or pointer)